# Getting access to a XML from javascript without Node-Without JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, xml

I am trying to developp modifications to a game. The thing is the game is already compiled and the developpers prefer not to decompile the game (for the time beeing). Because of the compilation probably, everytime I try to load JQuery or Node.js whatever version I get the error "that a key already exists in the dictionary". The thing is everything is fine without Node.js or JQuery.js.

What I am trying to achieve is add some features to the game that unfortunately aren't available through the Game's API function call itself. I want to be able to get access to data Inside .xml files used for items/weapons/devices/engines spécifications of items Inside the game. I've tried pretty much all I could find on Stackexchange with what I searched for which was Node and JQuery. Im sorry if you guys think this is a duplicate question. Because it isn't. I can't use Node.js neither can i use JQuery. What else could I try? can someone help me please.

I am a bit new to programing with only 1 year experience in c# and Javascript. Sorry if this feels really noObish to you guys.

Comment: You seem to think of NodeJS and jQuery as equivalent. jQuery is a client-side framework; NodeJS is a server-side *software*. There is no such thing as “loading” NodeJS into an application.

Comment: Oh yeah ok. No I didnt even knew it was client or server side in fact I don't even know what client side and server side software is. Im sorry. But what I do know is I have found marknote Parser and Im reading it right thinking it might be the solution to my problem. I need to find a function Inside of it that lets me fetch a .xml document and data Inside of it.

Comment: I don’t believe Marknote parses xml. There are much simplier ways to do what you want, as JS has built-in xml features. I’ll write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is ajax. Modern browsers provide a pretty functional `XMLHttpRequest`, so you don’t even need a framework anymore.

One important thing to know: you most likely won’t be able to download the xml file using ajax if it’s on a distant server, due to the same-origin policy. You need a reliable access to it. The most convenient solution is to have a copy of the file on a local server such as WAMP, XAMPP, and the like.

I’m not going to write yet another ajax tutorial. Insteal I’ll just provide you with a working minimal HTML page, and point you towards [XMLHttpRequest documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

```
<button>Request</button>
<script>
  'use strict';

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',
    function () {
      let req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      req.onload = function () {
        if (this.responseXML) {
          console.log(this.responseXML);
        }
        else {
          console.log(this.responseText);
        }
      };

      req.open('GET', xmlURL); // xmlURL should be the location of the .xml file
      req.send();
    });
</script>
```

When you click on the button, the script will request, and then display the server’s response, if any, in your browser console. To open the console, press F12 and select the console tab.

Be aware that the `responseXML` property will only be populated if the xml sent by the server is strictly well-formed. Xml parsing in JS is somewhat finicky, so you may want to rely on `responseText` as a fallback.

Comment: It's probably the best answer I could have... Unfortunately it doesnt work Watilin. I just received a response from the developpers of the game that only the API Scopes/functions of the game were provided for access. You know i can code but i dont know every détails about programing and thought that with any Scripting environment that I could access anything. I just don't get how functions of javascript can be blocked. I've also received the response that XMLHttpRequest is blocked also and cant be accessible. I'm not sure what to try next. Seems like an impossible task.

Comment: What do you mean “XMLHttpRequest is blocked”? What did you try? Did you get an error message or any indication?

Comment: I have tried your code snippet Inside my javascript file. The console debugs error message "[err] Script exception ! SyntaxError: Expected an expression but found '<' instead " at script.js line 705. I copy pasted the solution you gave except I change console.log for console.Print and also change the URL address to file://localhost/c:/VE/data/items/devices/weapon_ion_cannon.xml. It seems that I cannot use the <script> </script> or other similar annotations on my version of Javascript. The developpers said it was a EcmaS5 2011 version. Like I said

Comment: The developper said: As I told you:
1) there is no file system access from JS scripting in VE. You cannot access any game files there. Only what you can access with API or what you can define manually.
2) VE uses JavaScript, but only as a language for very limited scripting - it doesn't come with any browser-related API, the API is actually limited only to what we provide ("scopes") + basic JS syntax and features (such as arrays).  We didn't implemented anything else. For example, there is no XMLHttpRequest and I clearly see in the MarkNote sources it uses it. So it will not work.

Comment: I just hope I could find a way to hack javascript that they use to let me incorporate the functions I need. Ive got no clue where to start. Ill start searching information on that.

Comment: Also just wanted to point out that "import" or "const" or "window" or "document" "XDomainRequest" or "doc" or "XMLHttpRequest" are all undefined stuff. They are all unvalid expression or undefined.

Comment: My bad, I gave you wrong indications. You didn’t tell that you’re working in a special environment so I assumed it was a browser. What is VE?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. VE is short for Void Expanse. I was able to somehow fix my problem. Im using a xml generator that I built from c# to create an endless number of item files. Its still in early stage of development though - I dont need to access the files from within js now coz i get get at least the filename of the items. In the filename of the item is where I put all the necessary spécifications of the weapon automatically so that I can fetch them from javascript. Its the only function of javascript Inside the game that enables me to get information from a xml file.

Comment: But i got another question and might need to create another thread for that. I am thinking of building a listener c# script to listen to a javascript script by fetching a boolean or a variable and once conditions are made to rewrite the javascript array with data from the c# script. This would be the only way  to make use of c# Inside the game. I need it for multithreading. So the question is: Is it possible to access a javascript file Inside a wrapped file that has an extension called cpk (that is just a zip file renamed) when the javascript file is used or not used?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you’ve got zipped JavaScript. The ability to execute it only depends on the environment. I know at least one environment capable of this: Firefox with .xpi addons. Just like cpk, .xpi is .zip renamed and contains .js files. Check the Void Engine documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry again for the late reply Watilin. Ill start looking into how doing that.